# Discord - Add image from Google Drive in Embed Message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a list of files that I'm retrieving from Drive:

```
const list = await drive.files.list({
  q: `parents in '${process.env.DRIVE_DIR}' and name contains 'test_'`,
  spaces: 'drive',
  fields: 'files(id, mimeType, webViewLink)'
})
```

After getting the files I want to send embed messages with the image from Drive:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#6adada')
  .setTitle('Test')
  .setImage(list.data.files[index].webViewLink)
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```

I checked all permission on Google Drive and they are correct, if I access the link as a guest I can see the image in the browser. Is there something that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you log `list.data.files[index].webViewLink`?

Comment: @Leau I have the image link there, it's working fine. I can copy the link and paste in the browser. No probs

Comment: If you log `embed`, the link appears too?

Comment: @Leau yes the link is there, under the `image` property. `image: {
    url: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vAO4lmqykalD1uMaCNgaSj3aWi6myIU5/view?usp=drivesdk'
  },`

Comment: You can see that there isn't an image extension!

Comment: @Leau True idd. Do you know how can I change the link in order to have the file extension?

Comment: Sadly, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/67813895/14346900.

Comment: @Leau Thx a lot for that. It makes sense, gonna have to try a different approach

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using [FS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatewritestreamoptions) to download the file from drive, after that attaching it to the embed message using the `attachment` path in the `setImage` function. So after getting the `list` of files, I download it (in my case it will be always one file):

```
const { data } = await drive.files.get(
  {
    fileId: list.data.files[0].id,
    alt: "media"
  },
  { responseType: "stream" }
)

const fileName = fID + "." + mimeType.split("/")[1]
const file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)
data.on("end", () => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#6adada')
    .setTitle('Test Image')
    .setImage('attachment://' + fileName)
  message.channel.send({
    embeds: [embed],
    files: [fileName]
  })
  .then(() => {
    file.end()
    fs.unlinkSync(fileName)
  })
})
.on("error", error => message.reply(" Error: " + error.message))
.pipe(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the webViewLink to discord, where you change the usp query parameter in the URL from drivesdk to sharing.

For reference, this is the discord incoming webhook API: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

the google drive rest API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource

Check out a simple implementation of it here:

| Example Implementation | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70482916) |
| --- | --- |

```js
const { Integration } = require('@fusebit-int/framework');
const superagent = require('superagent')

const integration = new Integration();
const router = integration.router;
const googleConnector = 'googleConnector';
const discordConnector = 'discordConnector';
router.post('/api/tenant/:tenantId/test', async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const googleClient = await integration.tenant.getSdkByTenant(ctx, googleConnector, ctx.params.tenantId);

  const files = await googleClient
    .drive({
      version: 'v3',
    })
    .files.list({fields: 'files(id, mimeType, webViewLink)'});
  const file = files.data.files[0]
  file.webViewLink = file.webViewLink.replace('drivesdk', 'sharing')
  await discordSendMessage(ctx, file.webViewLink)
  ctx.body = {
    message: `Message with embed sent to discord.`,
  };
  } catch (e) {console.log(e)}
  
});

async function discordSendMessage(ctx, content) {
  const discordClient = await integration.tenant.getSdkByTenant(
    ctx,
    discordConnector,
    ctx.params.tenantId
  );
  const webhook = discordClient?.fusebit?.credentials?.webhook;
  if (!webhook) {
    ctx.throw(404, `The installation does not have a default webhook channel.`);
  }
  try {
  return await superagent.post(webhook.url).send({ content })} catch (e) {console.log(e)}
}

module.exports = integration;
```